# How to Combine many similar methods and views into one

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring

I want to combine similar methods and views into one, but still keep the url name, like the following:

```
Home/recommends/categories/shopping
Home/recommends/categories/nightview
Home/recommends/categories/food
Home/recommends/categories/area
```

I don't want to use params like `"?something=xyz"` in url.

In `routes.rb`:

```
resources :recommends, only: :index do
  collection do
    resources :categories, only: :show, controller: 'recommends' do
      collection do
        get :food
        get :area
        get :shopping
        get :nightview
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In controllers:

```
def food
  set_paginator
  @recommends = UserRecommend.where(category: "food").order('created_at desc').offset(@offset).limit(@limit).all
  @number_of_recommends = UserRecommend.where(category: "food").count
end

def area
  set_paginator
  @recommends = UserRecommend.where(category: "area").order('created_at desc').offset(@offset).limit(@limit).all
  @number_of_recommends = UserRecommend.where(category: "area").count
end

...
```

In views I have:

```
food.html.slim
area.html.slim
shopping.slim
nightview.slim
```

Which are using the same code, just different names in `h1`:

```
h1
  | Shopping ( or Area or Food... )
  = " (#{@number_of_recommends})"

= render partial: "layouts/paginator",
  locals: { total_items: @number_of_recommends, per_page: @limit, current_page: @page }

= render partial: "table", locals: { recommends: @recommends }
```

Can anyone help me refactor this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (and should) have a single route, a single action, and a single view. The key is to make the variable portion of your URL into an *actual variable*. You do this using [dynamic segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments).

First, a single route. There is no need to use `resources` if you're not actually generating multiple RESTful actions:

```
get "/recommends/categories/:category" => "categories#show"
```

You can add criteria on what is allowed for the `:category` segment:

```
get "/recommends/categories/:category" => "categories#show", category: /food|area|shopping|nightview/
```

Next, a single action:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_paginator

  def show
    # params[:category] is "food"/"area"/etc
    categories = UserRecommend.where(category: params[:category]).order('created_at desc')
    @recommends = categories.offset(@offset).limit(@limit)
    @number_of_recommends = categories.count
  end
end
```

Finally, a single view:

```
# app/views/categories/show.slim
h1
  = params[:category].capitalize
  = " (#{@number_of_recommends})"

= render partial: "layouts/paginator",
  locals: { total_items: @number_of_recommends, per_page: @limit, current_page: @page }

= render partial: "table", locals: { recommends: @recommends }
```

I would consider it better to use localization to turn the `params[:category]` into a title, which would give you more control, rather than relying on simple capitalization of the URL segment:

```
# app/views/categories/show.slim
h1
  = t params[:category]
```

And:

```
# config/locals/en.yml
en:
  categories:
    show:
      food: 'Food'
      area: 'Area'
      nightview: 'Night View'
```